# Define a line segment via relation

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In one of my books it says: It is possible to define a line segment without using coordinates or any kind of parametrization by using the relation "$\dots$ lies between $\dots$ and $\dots$". However this approach is not elaborated any further and I can't find more sources on this topic.

Does anyone here know how to define a line segment with just using a relation?

Comment: Search for Hilbert's axiom system for (Euclidean) geometry

Comment: I did. But I fail to see how the relation given above is a relation at all. How can one point be in relation with two other points?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to say that the segment $AB$ is the set of points that lie between $A$ and $B.$

Comment: That doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @Buh Why does this fail to help in any respect? How isn't it a possible answer to the last question in your OP?

Comment: Defining line segment is not the same as defining its length. Certainly you can't define the length of a segment with just betweenness relation but you can define just a segment like Allawonder did.